# Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 Detect Intent not working

Tags: c#, dialogflow-es

I am running this code below but get no answer from the API at the `DetectIntent()` line. I also tested the `DetectIntentsAsync()` method instead, but have the same problem.

I also call the bot from nodejs fulfillment and all responses were OK.

Code is below:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    messageList.Items.Add("User: " + messageText.Text);
    try
    {
        var query = new QueryInput
        {
            Text = new TextInput
            {
                Text = messageText.Text,
                LanguageCode = "en-us"
            }
        };

        var sessionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var agent = "...";
        var parameters = new JsonCredentialParameters
        {
            Type = JsonCredentialParameters.ServiceAccountCredentialType,
            ClientEmail = "...",
            PrivateKey = "..."
        };
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters);
        var creds = GoogleCredential.FromJson(json);

        var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(SessionsClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host, creds.ToChannelCredentials());

        var client = SessionsClient.Create(channel);

        var sessionName = new SessionName(agent, sessionId);

        var dialogFlow = client.DetectIntent(
            sessionName,
            query
        );
        channel.ShutdownAsync();

        messageList.Items.Add("Bot: " + dialogFlow);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        messageList.Items.Add("error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possibly an issue with the way you are calling `Async` methods without `await`ing them. You don't appear to be awaiting the `ShutdownAsync()` call, though that may not be relevant. If using the `DetectIntentAsync` method, you should be awaiting the response like so: `var result = await client.DetectIntentAsync(..., ...);`. To use `await`, you'll need to mark your method as `async`. If you need to read up on async-await in dotnet, I suggest you go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: i have tried with async as well :
private async Task callBot( string message) {
....
                Task<DetectIntentResponse> taskResponse = client.DetectIntentAsync(
                    sessionName,
                    query
                );
                dialogFlow = await taskResponse;
}


still no response from dialogflow, no errors